# how to fix the precision for lat/lng?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

with the v2 version we can fix the precision with toFixed
example: point.y.toFixed(4)
how can we do with the v3 version ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toFixed` is just JavaScript function - not from Google Maps API.

In API v3 you can do that during LatLng creating:

```
var latitude  = -25.363882;
var longitude = 131.044922;
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude.toFixed(4), longitude.toFixed(4));
```